# Access "params" in body of dag

Tags: airflow

I want to access the "params" of a dag in the body of the day, but I receive an error message that params is not defined. For example:

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
from airflow import DAG

default_args = {
    'owner': 'airflow',
    'retries': 0,
}

with DAG(
        dag_id="start-matrix",
        default_args=default_args,
        render_template_as_native_obj=True,
        params={
            'proj' : "team",
            'username' : "leebee",
        },
        schedule_interval=None,
        start_date=datetime(2021, 4, 5, 15, 0),
        catchup=False
) as dag:
    def test(proj, name, dag):
        print(proj + " " + name)
        pass

    test({{ params.proj }}, {{ params.username }}, dag)
    pass
```

But when I load the dag I get this error:

```
Broken DAG: [/local/airflow/dags/baddag.py] Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/local/airflow/dags/baddag.py", line 26, in <module>
    test({{ params.proj }}, {{ params.username }}, dag)
NameError: name 'params' is not defined
```

Is it possible to do this?

Answer (score 5):

Your function `test` isn't registered as an Airflow task. It's being called as a regular Python function. That won't work for two reasons:

1. The variable `params` isn't known within this scope (therefore you get that error)
2. Python will actually interpret `{{ ... }}` as a set in a set. Say `params` was replaced by a known variable, you'd still get an error because sets aren't hashable (try evaluating `{{ "test" }}`)

`params` is a variable known in Airflow *at runtime*. Meaning, when a task is executed in Airflow, a list of variables is gathered that is available whilst running the task. See the full list here: https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/templates-ref.html#variables.

To tell Airflow to call a Python function in a task, you could use the PythonOperator:

```py
from datetime import datetime

from airflow import DAG
from airflow.operators.python import PythonOperator

default_args = {
    "owner": "airflow",
    "retries": 0,
}

with DAG(
    dag_id="start-matrix",
    default_args=default_args,
    render_template_as_native_obj=True,
    params={
        "proj": "team",
        "username": "leebee",
    },
    schedule_interval=None,
    start_date=datetime(2021, 4, 5, 15, 0),
    catchup=False,
) as dag:

    def test(proj, name):
        print(proj + " " + name)
        pass

    PythonOperator(
        task_id="test",
        python_callable=test,
        op_kwargs={"proj": "{{ params.proj }}", "name": "{{ params.username }}"},
    )
```

Let's break it down. First, the import:

```py
from airflow.operators.python import PythonOperator
```

Next, the PythonOperator:

```py
PythonOperator(
    task_id="test",
    python_callable=test,
    op_kwargs={"proj": "{{ params.proj }}", "name": "{{ params.username }}"},
)
```

The arguments:

- `task_id` represents the name of the task in the UI
- `python_callable` references the Python function this task should call
- `op_kwargs` is a way to pass arguments to the function referenced by `python_callable`. Since we don't know the value of `params.proj` at runtime yet, you'll need to supply *templated* variables, which are strings evaluated at runtime. So e.g. `"{{ params.proj }}"` is evaluated at runtime, meaning at runtime the value of `params.proj` is looked up and the templated string is replaced by the value of `params.proj`. This value is then given to the argument named `proj`. Read more about templating here: https://docs.astronomer.io/learn/templating.

A slightly shorter way to write this in Airflow is with the TaskFlow API (see [1](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/tutorial/taskflow.html), [2](https://docs.astronomer.io/learn/airflow-decorators)):

```py
from datetime import datetime

from airflow import DAG
from airflow.decorators import task
from airflow.operators.python import get_current_context

default_args = {
    "owner": "airflow",
    "retries": 0,
}

with DAG(
    dag_id="start-matrix",
    default_args=default_args,
    render_template_as_native_obj=True,
    params={
        "proj": "team",
        "username": "leebee",
    },
    schedule_interval=None,
    start_date=datetime(2021, 4, 5, 15, 0),
    catchup=False,
) as dag:

    @task
    def test():
        context = get_current_context()
        print(context["params"]["proj"] + " " + context["params"]["username"])

    test()
```

Here, you don't have to provide `proj` and `username` via function arguments, but can fetch their values from the `context` which is fetched with `get_current_context()`. The `@task` decorator automatically turns the function into a PythonOperator internally. When using Python functions only, this is generally a preferred way of writing Airflow code.

Comment: Note you don't need to import and call `get_current_context()`, you can define the test task as `def test(**context)` and have access to it.